# converting HTML button to CSS Switch to function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I  have the following code that works very nice and sweetly

- **HTML**

```
<button id="changeColor">changeColor</button>
```

-**Javascript**

```js
 <script>



document.getElementById("changeColor").addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("Bkground")[0].style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("changeColor").check ? "white" : "black";
});

    </script>
```

**- I would like to use the CSS Switch below instead of the HTML button to switch between white and black**

```html
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

</style>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

-please note that my class is "Bkground" that's why I had `document.getElementsByClassName(Bkground)`

- I want to fix two things
- **I would like to use the CSS Switch instead of the HTML button to switch between white and black**
- **I want to be able to switch between two colors (black and white) when the button being clicked**

  like

```
 <script>



if ( document.getElementById("changeColor").addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper fullWidth")[0].style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("changeColor").changeColor ? "white" : "black");
   
   else ( document.getElementById("changeColor").addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper fullWidth")[0].style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("changeColor").changeColor ? "black" : "white");)
   
   
});

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simple change (add and remove a CSS class), and change UI based on it. This will be easiest.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#changeColor").click(function(){
    $("p").toggleClass("changed");
    $("#changeColor").toggleClass("changed");
    $("body").toggleClass("changed");
  });
});
```

```css
body {background: pink;}
body.changed {background:gray;}

button {background: yellow;}
button.changed {background: green;}

p {background: orange;}
p.changed {background: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="changeColor">Toggle</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: it's not the same design dude !